# I currently have a form that sends a value to my mvc controller. I'd like to change it from a dropdown to a image link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, drop-down-menu, menu, radio-button

I currently have a form that sends a value to my mvc controller. I'd like to change it from a dropdown select menu, to a image with three different image links carrying the user choice value. Here is my code below. Right now when the user chooses one of the drop-down options the value is passed once they hit submit. Some important lines in this code are the using statement and the name ddlLanguage. This is what makes the magic happen and changes the language. I simply need to recreate this same form so that a user sees three images as buttons or links that work as the user option selected. How can I do this and still pass the values using helpers ("@") and the class form-control since they seem to be essential to passing the data? My Home controller form collector is below.

```
 public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {

        string language = "en";
        language = collection["ddlLanguage"];
        SetCulture(language);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }





@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmId", @class = "frmStyle" }))//something wrong with this will not recoginize index/home
        {
            <label style="color:white">@Global.SelectLanguage:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="ddlLanguage" style="display:inline-block">
                    <!--class="form-control" bootstrap stacks form boxes-->
                    <option value="en">@Global.English</option>
                    <option value="es">@Global.Spanish</option>
                    <option value="fr">@Global.French</option>
                    @*add new languages here*@
                </select>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="@Global.Submit" style="display:inline-block" /><!--class="form-control" bootstrap stacks form boxes-->
```

Comment: you want to change the dropdown to 3 links ? Why not create 3 anchor tags ?

Comment: I mean no dropdown. Just three links with values that take in a form setting

Comment: Do you still want the submit button to submit the form ? Or clicking on the link should submit the form ?

Comment: clicking on the link should submit the form

Comment: So far I have the submit part down. It's the passing the option value that I can't figure out.                                                                                                                 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('frmId').submit()"><img src="~/Content/Images/canada_small.png" /></a>
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('frmId').submit()"><img src="~/Content/Images/france_small.png" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can listen to the `click` event on the link, read the value you want to pass, set that to a hidden input with the name same as what your HttpPost action method is expecting.

```
<a href="#" class="langLink" data-val="en">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/france_small.png" />English
</a>
<a href="#" class="langLink" data-val="fr">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/france_small.png" />Fench
</a>
<input type="hidden" name="ddlLanguage" value="" />
```

You can use jQuery to wire up your javascript code

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     $(".langLink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // Set the value from data attribute to the hidden input field.

        $("input[name='ddlLanguage']").val($(this).data("val"));
        //Submit the form
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
     });
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT :** *As per the comment.* 
If you want to simply use the links instead of hidden filed, you can simply set the `href` attribute value of your link to your Index action.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home",new {id="en"})">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/france_small.png" />English
</a>
```

And in your Index action, have a parameter to accept the language name

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
   //check Id param value. and do something
}
```

With this approach you are not really doing a form submit. It is just a new GET request to the Index action with the language name as querystring.

Comment: I added the code for the form collection above in my orignal post. Something seems to be off with the wired up javascript code. I have jquery working and the submit form part of the iimages is working but the data isnt passing through the attribute data-val="en" or "fr". It passes fine through the dropdown but not with this javascript. I don't know why it is submitting the form but not passing the value still?

Comment: It should work fine. Make sure your input name is correct. Here is a working sample for you to compare. http://jsbin.com/nezedaniyo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks Man! It works! I just had to add type = submit on the input portion. I'd like to upvote but I have to earn 15 reputation points.

Comment: Shyju sir, is there anyway I can do it without the input element. In other words, can I have the france image links submit the form as opposed to having an input element that submits the form? right now it seems a bit confusing. It is passing the value yes but I just want it to be a submit button with a value. Is this possible?

Comment: I tried using the (this).closest("form") but it doesn't seem to be working as well

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer. If you want to use links, It is not a form submission. It is just a GET request

Comment: That works too, but that takes me to a url. I mean the image has a value not a link. for example the <a href= takes in a parameter value for data-value. I need this to pass through just as though it were a submit button.